# How to remove Google Meet in the email notification received after creating a Google event?

Tags: ruby, google-calendar-api

[image]

```
class SendInvitation
  def self.new(match_info,current_user)

    begin

      authorization = GoogleRefresh.auth_client(current_user)
      service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
      service.authorization = authorization

      match_date = match_info.match_date.strftime("%F")
      min_time = match_info.min_time.strftime("%T%:z")
      max_time = match_info.max_time.strftime("%T%:z")
      start_time = "#{match_date}T#{min_time}"
      end_time = "#{match_date}T#{max_time}"

      minutes = ((start_time.to_time-Time.now) / 60).to_i

      attendeesList = Match.find(id=match_info.id).users.map{|user| Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee.new(email: "#{user.email}")}
      attendeesList<<Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee.new(email: "#{User.find(id=match_info.owner_id).email}")



      event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(
          summary: "CalendarMatcher -#{match_info.title}",
          location: match_info.location,
          description: "Descritption: #{match_info.description}",


           start: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(
            date_time: start_time,
            time_zone: 'Europe/Brussels'
            ),
          end: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(
            date_time: end_time,
            time_zone: 'Europe/Brussels'
            ),

        attendees:  attendeesList,

        reminders: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event::Reminders.new(
          use_default: false,
          overrides: [
            Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventReminder.new(
              reminder_method: 'email',
              minutes: minutes
              ),
            Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventReminder.new(
              reminder_method: 'popup',
              minutes: 30
              )
          ]
          )
        )


        result = service.insert_event('primary', event)



        puts "Event created: #{updated_result.html_link}"

      rescue ::Google::Apis::AuthorizationError => e
      authorization.grant_type = 'refresh_token'
      authorization.access_token = current_user.token
      authorization.refresh_token = current_user.refresh_token
      response = authorization.refresh!
      current_user.token = response['access_token']
      current_user.save

      retry
    end

  end
end
```

I am struggling with google api documentation... I am a really junior developper and hope that someone will be able to help me.

Here is all my method to send the email to the attendees and to add the event in the attendees calendar. It is working fine : it send email and fill their calendar.

But the email include the GoogleMeet link which I would like to remove.
So I read all the documentation on the internet. For what I understood, the GoogleMeet respond to some "conference data" settings...

But when I start adding conference_data_version: 1.
`result = service.insert_event('primary', event, conference_data_version: 1);`
I get the error saying that **"unknown keyword: conference_data_version"**

Comment: Can you please provide screenshots of what it is you're trying to remove? It isn't clear with what you have so far

Comment: So here the link to the picture :   https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVQJY.png . I am not able at the moment to add picture... Thanks already for reading my post ;).

Comment: What picture are you wanting to add?

Comment: I don't want to add a picture. I would like to remove the GoogleMeet link in the email send. I saw things on the internet to remove the conference settings but nothing is working for me. Thanks in advance if you have any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You need to set `conference_data_version` to `1`.*

#### Code change:

```ruby
result = service.insert_event('primary', event, conference_data_version: 0)
```

should be changed to:

```ruby
result = service.insert_event('primary', event, conference_data_version: 1)
```

Also, you do not need to specify an empty `conference_data: {}` object in the event resource.

---

Here is my full code so you can see how this is done.

The authorize function was taken from the Ruby Quickstart provided by Google, and the Calendar insert was modified based on the client documentation:

```ruby
require "google/apis/calendar_v3"
require "googleauth"
require "googleauth/stores/file_token_store"
require "date"
require "fileutils"

OOB_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".freeze
APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Calendar API Ruby Quickstart".freeze
CREDENTIALS_PATH = "credentials.json".freeze
# The file token.yaml stores the user 's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.

TOKEN_PATH = "token.yaml".freeze
SCOPE = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR

##
# Ensure valid credentials, either by restoring from the saved credentials
# files or intitiating an OAuth2 authorization.If authorization is required, 
# the user 's default browser will be launched to approve the request.
#
# @return [Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials] OAuth2 credentials

def authorize
  client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file CREDENTIALS_PATH
  token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new file: TOKEN_PATH
  authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new client_id, SCOPE, token_store
  user_id = "default"
  credentials = authorizer.get_credentials user_id
  if credentials.nil ?
    url = authorizer.get_authorization_url base_url : OOB_URI
    puts "Open the following URL in the browser and enter the "\
         "resulting code after authorization:\n" + url
    code = gets
    credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
      user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI
    )
  end
  credentials
end

# Initialize the API
service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize

event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(
    summary: "CalendarMatcher -#{match_info.title}",
    location: match_info.location,
    description: "Descritption: #{match_info.description}",
    start: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(
        date_time: start_time,
        time_zone: 'Europe/Brussels'
    ),
    end: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(
        date_time: end_time,
        time_zone: 'Europe/Brussels'
    ),
    attendees: [
        Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee.new(
            email: 'email@domain.com'
        ),
        Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee.new(
            email: 'email2@domain.com'
        )
    ],
    reminders: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event::Reminders.new(
        use_default: false,
        overrides: [
            Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventReminder.new(
                reminder_method: 'email',
                minutes: minutes
            ),
            Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventReminder.new(
                reminder_method: 'popup',
                minutes: 30
            )
        ]
    )
)
result = service.insert_event('primary', event, conference_data_version: 1)
```

Make sure to delete your `token.yaml` file and re-run your program.

Comment: So I change for :
result = service.insert_event('primary', event, conference_data_version: 1)

But I get the error :  ***"unknown keyword: conference_data_version"***.  :(


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMrMf.png

Comment: @sarnico What have you changed in your code? How was it running before with it set to 0 if it's now an unknown keyword? Are you sure you're calling the right service?

Comment: @sarnico I have updated my answer to provide my full code.

Comment: _@Rafa Guillermo_, I am still working on what you send me. But I still don't get whats the purpose of the ** OOB_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".freeze** . Can you please inlight me of what I shoud put for thet OOB_URI ? For the moment, I juste get some error _The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type. You can create a Client ID for native application at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient_

Comment: Just use your original code and change `conference_data_version` to `1`. If it was working before when it was set to `0` then you changed something between when you posted your question and I posted an answer. I can not know what it is you did. The code I posted to which you reference was a modified version of the [quickstart provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/ruby).

Comment: Sorry I guess I am not clear at all in my explanation... I wrote a new post trying to explain better but as I posted it as answer it had been deleted. Sorry about that. Now, I updated my original post ! My code is working fine until I tried to enter the conference settings.... So It has never worked with `result = service.insert_event('primary', event, conference_data_version: 1)`. 0 or 1 ;). I have no clue why because everybody seems so do it without any issue.